# Protecting and unprotecting identical ranges across multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I teach a middle school robotics class and we do an inventory check every six weeks to make sure that all the pieces are there.  I would like to track over different class periods how the inventory is going.  I would like to write a script that would allow me to click a button to lock down all columns across all sheets except for the column that I want students to edit.

In other words, during 1st period the only column that students could edit is column G.  Then I click a button/icon at the end of class and that column is locked.

I then click another button/icon and only 2nd period (column H) is open.  I then click it to lock down again.

I know that I could do this by clicking protect cells but I am trying to find a more efficient way.

Here is the spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E6DV4yHnTdwfmSTmSSFY3gY6eYJMx7dSqUjEzNdvVO0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you are over-complicating things.

- You have a spreadsheet that will serve as a template.
- In each of the "bucket" sheets,

  - delete contents of "G1:M1", "G23:M23", "G32:M32", "G41:M41", "G67:M67", "G76:M76", "G85:M85", "G98:M98", "G107:G107"
  - Cell G1, G23,G32,G41,G67,G76,G95,G98,G107 = "Actual Counted"
- Each time you want to do a stocktake,

  - make a copy of the "template'
  - name the new spreadsheets for the "period" group AND the date. For example, "Period 1_ 202201112_22-23 Spike Inventory Stocktake"
  - when these files are saved, they will sort by "period" and then by date.
- Conditional formatting

  - if you wish, you could use conditional formatting to highlight cells to stocktake, and some results such as "=expected qty","<>expected qty", and "negative"

---

**Sample conditional formatting**

[image: sample]